# How to change the color of my heading when a div is hovered?

Tags: html, css

```
    <div class="apply_block">
        <h2>Common Application to Undergraduate</h2>
        <h3 class="head_eng">College of Engineering</h3>
        <h3 class="head_sci">College of Science</h3>
        <h3 class="head_int">College of Interdisciplinary Studies</h3>
        <div class="engineering" id="eng_college"></div>
    </div>
```

i wanted to change the color of .head_eng when .engineering is hovered. I tired to use the dash;

```
.engineering:hover ~ .head_eng{
    background-color: #94b5e8;  
}
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work. is there a way to fix this?